# Meteor remove value from array object from collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am trying to remove array values from collection. Data is inserting in "comments"  table when any user add comment and other users replies are inserting as array in "replies" filed which is in comments table as array. If i delete a parent comment then it's working fine when trying to remove any replied comment from array then it's not working.

This is condition which i am using.It's going into else but not removing value from array field.

```
deleteComment(comment) {

    let commentId = comment.commentId; //
    let replyComntID = comment.repID;
    if(replyComntID == 0)
    {   
      Comments.remove({_id: commentId});

    }else{

        Comments.remove({_id: comment.commentId, "replies._id":comment.replyComntID});


    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `remove()` [method](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/) removes an entire document from your collection

So removing the parent comment works because the entire document is removed

But for removing the reply, you don't want to remove the document, just one item from an array in the document - so you need the `update()` [method](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/)

Specifically you need to use the `$pull` [operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#up._S_pull) to remove the item from the array

So your answer would look something like this (without knowing what your schema looks like):

`Comments.update({ _id: commentId }, { $pull: { replies: { _id: replyComntID } } })`

See the [mongo docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#examples) for how $pull works

Comment: @user3714488 In that case I think you'll have to post your collection schema (or just an example document) - it's hard to know what exactly the issue is from the info you've provided

Comment: it's working in my case i have changed this 
Comments.update({ _id: commentId }, { $pull: { replies  : { _id: replyComntID  }}})